# add class to a specific ng-repeat item and stay on that item

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm working on a chatapp. The messages in the chatapp are populated with ng-repeat. When the user logs out of the app or closes the app I want the current last item (message) in the ng-repeat list to be marked with a class name and that it stays with that specific item (message). So that when the user comes back it can see what the last message was he read.

I have no trouble with marking the last item (message) with a class name only when new messages are added to the list the class name is always on the last item (message). So always the last item (message) will be marked, the class name doesn't stick to that specific item (message).

Has someone an idea how to handle this ?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you making the class evaluation based on the data or in the DOM?  If you mark the actual data item, it should re-evaluate correctly.

Comment: You have to flag this message as read somewhere. You must save this flag with the message.

Comment: @KnowHowSolutions it's based on the DOM

Comment: When a user leaves the app I could add a message with a date and time stamp for example but I thought maybe there is a simple solution via the DOM so I can add a class name with a subtle style change

Comment: "leaving the app" does that mean the whole angular app or just a view?  You are a bit unclear on this.  If you are leaving the whole app, you have to mark the data on the server.  If you are not leaving the whole app then I would suggest pushing your data into a factory and marking the message there as required and re-eval on the next view/apply.

Comment: @KnowHowSolutions: Yes with "leaving the app" I mean the whole angular app. Unfortunately marking the data on the server is not an option. I use a third party plugin and I can not add / mark current data. And I realize now that like the example in my previous comment it is not going to work. If I could change or add data on the server, if I do that it is reflected to all users. and this is user specific

Comment: @KnowHowSolutions Can I manually add a ng-repeat item to the dom?

Comment: You could try using a cookie - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies  that would be local to your user, non-server, just read/lookup it at app start.

Comment: @PSL referenced something which was interesting in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30361765/how-to-have-unique-scope-in-ng-repeat-in-angularjs) -- would you be able to use the unique `$$id` of the last `ng-repeat` item to change its class? and perhaps you can have data persistence with client-side `local storage` when a user "leaves the app".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my own problem as follow:

When the app goes to the background I manually insert an item to the ng-repeat.
this is only visible for the specific user. New messages will be added below this and so the user can see where he was and which messages are new.

```
//do something when app goes to the background
            document.addEventListener('pause', function() {
                $timeout(function(){
                    $scope.messages.push('messages below this line are new');
                },0);
            },false);
```

html:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="message in messages">...</ion-item>
```